# Find max number from a table of a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a Table name 'IpRelay' and 'volt' is one of the column name. I extract maximum voltage from volt column.

here is my controller code

```
$this->set('max_num', $this->IpRelay->query("SELECT MAX(volt) FROM ip_relays"));
```

and here is my view code

```
<?php echo $max_num; ?>
```

But it doesn't work. It gives me a notice "Array to string conversion ".

Comment: try <?php print_r($max_num); ?>

Comment: I have tried this. It gives me  "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [MAX(volt)] => 562 ) ) )" this type of values. But I don't understand how do I extract only value "562".

Comment: You are passing an array entirely. You need to pass $max_num[0][0]['MAX(volt)']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in controller code:

```
$this->set('max_num', $this->IpRelay->query("SELECT MAX(volt) AS max_num FROM ip_relays"));
```

And view code:

```
<?php echo $max_num[0][0]['max_num']; ?>
```

You need to use array in the view code because `query` method result is `array`.

Answer (score 0):

it will always return an array regardless of how many result you are trying to fetch, you need to get the first element. try:

```
<?php echo $max_num[0] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to

```
$this->set('max_num', $this->IpRelay->query("SELECT MAX(volt) AS max_volt FROM ip_relays"));
```

and you can echo like this

```
echo $max_num[0]['max_volt'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why running a custom query. Try cakephp orm

```
$max = $this->IpRelay->find('all', 
        array(
            'fields' => array(
                'MAX(IpRelay.volt) AS max_value'
            ))
        );
    debug($max[0][0]['max_value']);

   $this->set('max_num', $max[0][0]['max_value']);
```

echo max_num in view. I hope you will get the max value.